# How to set an active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i did a tabbed menu on bootstrap. But i can't figure out active tab

How to style active tab, When i  define active class, it only effects first tab.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEVJ7.jpg)

heres my code below

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
   jQuery(function($){
       $(".circle").children("circle").click(function(){
           $(".active").removeClass("active");
       });
   });
</script>
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- Nav tabs --><div class="d-none d-sm-block girintile">
<ul class="nav nav-justified" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#section-1" role="tab"> <div class="team-box"> <img src="kisi.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle circle active"> <h4 class="no-a">Yunus Melih Gözütok</h4><p>CEO</p> </div></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#section-2" role="tab"><div class="team-box"> <img src="kisi.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle circle"> <h4 class="no-a">Yunus Melih Gözütok</h4><p>CEO</p> </div></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#section-3" role="tab"><div class="team-box"> <img src="kisi.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle circle"> <h4 class="no-a">Yunus Melih Gözütok</h4><p>CEO</p> </div></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#section-4" role="tab"><div class="team-box"> <img src="kisi.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle circle"> <h4 class="no-a">Yunus Melih Gözütok</h4><p>CEO</p> </div></a>
  </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#section-5" role="tab"><div class="team-box"> <img src="kisi.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle circle"> <h4 class="no-a">Yunus Melih Gözütok</h4><p>CEO</p> </div></a>
  </li>
</ul></div>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content girintile "><br>
  <div class="tab-pane box active" id="section-1" role="tabpanel"><h4 class="bg-grey">Yunus Melih Gözütok</h4><p class="text-justified girintile"> yunus</p></div>
  <div class="tab-pane box" id="section-2" role="tabpanel"><h4 class="bg-grey">Yunus Melih Gözütok1</h4><p class="text-justified girintile"> melih</p></div>
  <div class="tab-pane box" id="section-3" role="tabpanel"><h4 class="bg-grey">Yunus Melih Gözütok2</h4><p class="text-justified girintile"> gözütok</p></div>
  <div class="tab-pane box" id="section-4" role="tabpanel"><h4 class="bg-grey">Yunus Melih Gözütok3</h4><p class="text-justified girintile"> lipsum</p></div>
  <div class="tab-pane box" id="section-5" role="tabpanel"><h4 class="bg-grey">Yunus Melih Gözütok4</h4><p class="text-justified girintile"> lipsum</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Reference for you. check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/qb8b4hcj/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just added some active class with red color text, when u click on each item color red will apply and remaining will be same as blue color text

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
    .active{
      color:red !important;
    }
    </style>
      <script>
   $(".nav-item .nav-link").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".nav-item .nav-link").not($(this)).removeClass("active");
})
</script>
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- Nav tabs --><div class="d-none d-sm-block girintile">
<ul class="nav nav-justified" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#section-1" role="tab"> <div class="team-box"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Codero_Hosting_Logo_%28100px%29.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle circle active"> <h4 class="no-a">Yunus Melih Gözütok</h4><p>CEO</p> </div></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#section-2" role="tab"><div class="team-box"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Codero_Hosting_Logo_%28100px%29.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle circle"> <h4 class="no-a">Yunus Melih Gözütok</h4><p>CEO</p> </div></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#section-3" role="tab"><div class="team-box"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Codero_Hosting_Logo_%28100px%29.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle circle"> <h4 class="no-a">Yunus Melih Gözütok</h4><p>CEO</p> </div></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#section-4" role="tab"><div class="team-box"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Codero_Hosting_Logo_%28100px%29.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle circle"> <h4 class="no-a">Yunus Melih Gözütok</h4><p>CEO</p> </div></a>
  </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#section-5" role="tab"><div class="team-box"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Codero_Hosting_Logo_%28100px%29.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle circle"> <h4 class="no-a">Yunus Melih Gözütok</h4><p>CEO</p> </div></a>
  </li>
</ul></div>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content girintile "><br>
  <div class="tab-pane box active" id="section-1" role="tabpanel"><h4 class="bg-grey">Yunus Melih Gözütok</h4><p class="text-justified girintile"> yunus</p></div>
  <div class="tab-pane box" id="section-2" role="tabpanel"><h4 class="bg-grey">Yunus Melih Gözütok1</h4><p class="text-justified girintile"> melih</p></div>
  <div class="tab-pane box" id="section-3" role="tabpanel"><h4 class="bg-grey">Yunus Melih Gözütok2</h4><p class="text-justified girintile"> gözütok</p></div>
  <div class="tab-pane box" id="section-4" role="tabpanel"><h4 class="bg-grey">Yunus Melih Gözütok3</h4><p class="text-justified girintile"> lipsum</p></div>
  <div class="tab-pane box" id="section-5" role="tabpanel"><h4 class="bg-grey">Yunus Melih Gözütok4</h4><p class="text-justified girintile"> lipsum</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code will do

```
$(".nav-item .nav-link").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".nav-item .nav-link").not($(this)).removeClass("active");
})
```